# How to install (run) Jumo (Python/Django) on localhost

Tags: python, django

I am trying to run [Jumo](http://www.jumo.com/) open source platform ( https://github.com/jumoconnect/openjumo) on my local machine (Windows 7). I have Python and Django installed and it works - I can create new project without problems, but I am not sure how to set existing project and make it work.

I am not experienced with Python/Django, so first I need to know whether it is hard task or not. I guess it's much complicated then installing WordPress or Joomla, but does that require a lot of work in order to set it up?

Can someone write some kind of guide if it is not too complicated? Or if there is some tutorial that explains how to do that, that would be great.

Just to be clear, I am not trying to learn something in one day, just want to see if this first step in using this platform is too hard, and if it's not, I'd continue learning, because this is exactly what I need for one project.

I use Python 2.7 and Django 1.3.1

Thanks

Comment: Only a bit more complicated because code is not hosted on public HTML directory. But is for testing or developing pour pluses is enought with python manage.py runserver

Comment: Yes, I did "python manage.py runserver" and I get Import error: No module named celery.schedules .. when I start new project it works fine. I know that error is there, but I am affraid if there is going to be more erors after I solve this one, that's why I need someone to tell me if it can be installed easily, or I should have to spend more then few weeks in learning Python/Django (I have in plan to do that, but I'd like to test this script first).

Comment: Your project has requeriments. Perhaps you need to install celery.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I should definitelly spend more time in learning Python at first, and then Django.

Comment: To run py apps, see this simple tutorial: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242434/how-to-run-python-scripts-on-a-web-servere-g-localhost**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This project has a lot of external requirements which are not listed anywhere and unless you are comfortable and familiar with django, I wouldn't recommend installing it. Here are some ***but not all*** of the requirements that you'll need running:

1. [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/install/) and [django-celery](https://github.com/ask/django-celery)
2. [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/download.html) (a broker for Celery), or another broker but then you'll have to edit [settings.py](https://github.com/jumoconnect/openjumo/blob/master/jumodjango/settings.py) again.
3. [memcached](http://www.couchbase.com/downloads/membase-server/community) (this is optional, as you can use django's own session middleware for development), but if you simply download the code and try to run it, you'll run into an error since the default [settings.py](https://github.com/jumoconnect/openjumo/blob/master/jumodjango/settings.py) has the default middleware commented out.
4. [grappelli](https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-grappelli)
5. [django-jenkins](https://github.com/kmmbvnr/django-jenkins) (not required, but again, unless you edit the default [settings.py](https://github.com/jumoconnect/openjumo/blob/master/jumodjango/settings.py), you'll get errors).
6. [django-tastypie](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie)
7. [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar)
8. [Data science toolkit server](http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/developerdocs#setup)

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. It helped me to see that it's a bit complicated, so what I have to do now is to continue learning before taking further steps :)

Answer (score 0):

as you may know Django is a powerful web framework and Python is a programming language, for python itself you need more than a few months to become some kind of expert.
it's very easy to start, but not that easy to learn the whole stuff. Django is one of the most or maybe the most powerful web frameworks (beside Ruby on Rails).
my advice to you:

- learn python's basics (there's many books such as dive into python,
  ...)
- learn Django basics ([Django Book](http://www.djangobook.com))
- use Django on a Gnu/Linux (for example Ubuntu)

learning basics of Django can be done in a few weeks.
consider deploying a Django website is not that easy. you need to know a little about Apache web server.
[www.djangoproject.com](http://www.djangoproject.com)

note that in python (like other programming languages) you need to define working path. errors mentioned in question's comments usually caused by this.
also you should check Python installation path. sometimes these kinds of errors occurs when there is a project with the same name as yours in python installation path.

Comment: I already started learning basics, realized that I will need more time then few days in order to dive into this kind of project. Thanks.