# Delivering Python Processed data to the web

Tags: python, html, web

I have developed a python program that parses a webpage and creates a new text document with the parsed data. I want to deliver this new information to the web. I have no idea where to start with something like this. Are there any free options where I can have a site automatically call this python code upon request and update the new data to its page? Or is the only feasible solution here to have my own website/server that uses my code? I'm honestly pretty overwhelmed with many of the options when I try to begin doing a web-search for a solution like this. I have done a decent amount of application programming before so i'm confident in my ability to learn new things, but web protocols are all new to me so its hard to find a starting point.

Ultimately I want this python code to run automatically, or per request of a user, and deliver to the data to them. It could even be through an email, although that is probably less practical.

Answer (score 0):

I personally have good experience using [Google Appengine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/) (and its free for a limited amount of requests). The downside is that it does not allow C-extensions or Python3.

If you want to host your own server, [tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/) is a good option I think. Tornado supports both Python2 and Python3.

Answer (score 0):

There are a great deal of options available.. from 'traditional' virtual server or website hosts like [a2hosting](http://www.a2hosting.com/) or [godaddy](http://www.godaddy.com/) to 'Cloud Application Hosts' such as [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/), [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) or [OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/).

For your case, and without knowing more, I would suggest that an application hosting is more appropriate, and that you should take a look at Heroku and Openshift in particular.

Define carefully what you want to achieve (*how the users access your application, what they see, how they interact with it... etc..*) and then evaluate these options based on those requirements.

Most offer a free trial, or even free services, depending on what you need! Good luck

Answer (score 0):

If you've never worked with web technologies before this will be a overwhelming task, since there's a lot of different technologies involved, and many possible ways to combine them.

You'll probably want to start by familiarizing yourself with the very [basics of the HTTP protocol](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/webprogramming/http_basics.html). 
Then you should read a bit on [CGI server-side programming](http://www.garshol.priv.no/download/text/http-tut.html) (the article also has a quick overview on HTTP).

Python can run both on CGI and WSGI (if the server provider allows such access), so you may also want to read about [WSGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface).

Once you grasp all these concepts, you should [check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20242434) for actual python techniques.

Also, since you seem to be under the impression you must pay to have a website/app deployed, you should know there are [companies that host python apps for free](https://wiki.python.org/moin/FreeHosts)